# To improve Tesseract Accuracy

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I have been developing an application for License Plate Recognition and I am able to detect the number plate successfully from the image using OpenCV. But the problem is with the output of Tesseract e.g. if there is a number say "BI6 COL" in image, Tesseract detect it as "BISWCDL"
I have tried several image preprocessing methods (resampling,morphological operations, binarization...) but the accuracy in results is still low.

Please suggest how can I improve the quality of output

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on number plate recognition, I would recommend you to train Tesseract exclusively for number plate characters as per your country, considering most countries have different fonts used for writing on the number plate. Pre-processing the image will not much of a difference unless you train Tesseract to recognize characters on number plate.

**USEFUL LINKS**

- I would recommend you to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268648/using-tesseract-to-recognize-license-plates) Stack Overflow thread.
- If you wish to train Tesseract, check out [this](https://github.com/openalpr/train-ocr) git repository.